# How can I access the title or text of an "a" nested within a "td" using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, .net

I have a calendar where the day cells are clickable "td" elements. Inside each is an "a" that has a title. I need to use this title in a JavaScript function that is called when any of the "td" elements are clicked. I had to disable the PostBack for all "a" elements

Here is code for one of the cells:

```
<td align="center" style="width:14%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$Calendar2','6314')" style="color:Black" title="April 15">15</a></td>
```

I just need to access the 15 text technically. I can get the month elsewhere.

Is this possible using JavaScript?

Comment: You question is not clear. Do you want to add a listener to each of the A elements, or do you want to access the title property from within the *__doPostBack* function? It seems to me you should be using a span with click listener, not an A element.

Comment: @RobG So when the TD is clicked, a JavaScript function is called. When is is called I need a way to use the text of the A that is within the TD that was clicked. I can't change these elements. I can't change the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery for this would be a pretty good idea since you can select elements pretty conveniently. With jQuery you'd use:

`$('td a').attr('title');`

If you still want to use pure Javascript, you can select the title of the element by using:

`document.querySelectorAll('td a')[0].title;`

In the end, they both get the job done but the jQuery code is shorter.

So you'd do something similar to this with jQuery.

```js
$('td a').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>
    <tb>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" title="hi"> Hey </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" title="hi2"> Oh </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" title="hi3"> Goodbye </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tb>
  </th>

</table>
```

Comment: the jQuery code might be shorter, but you just added 10,000 lines of code to the page… ; -)

Comment: Save that load time by using a CDN. :P

Comment: Will this give the title of only the A within the TD that was clicked by the user? If yes, would using $('td a').attr('text') give me the text "15" in the example I provided?

Comment: @AndrewMcCracken Check out my latest edit. To get the text in the anchor tag you'd do `$(this).text()`

Comment: @qxest Works like a charm, and very simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what you're after, but if you can control the call, then including *this* in the call gives you a reference to the element that called the listener, e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$Calendar2','6314', this)"...>
```

Then in the listener, you have a reference to the element and you can get its *title* property directly, e.g.

```
function __doPostBack(arg0, arg1, element) {
  var title = element.title;
  // title is the value of the element's title property
}
```

> I had to disable the PostBack for all "a" elements

I don't understand what that means. If it means you don't want to use `__doPostBack` to get the title and want to add a listener to each of the links, then you can do that quite simply too:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td a'), function(a){
    a.addEventListener('click', showTitle, false)
  });
};

function showTitle(){
  console.log(this.title);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><a href="#" title="foo">foo
  <tr><td><a href="#" title="bar">bar
  <tr><td><a href="#" title="fum">fum
</table>
```